Is anyonle else having problems with USB 3 ports on a Raspbery Pi 5 vs Pi 4?
I have 2 issues

I upgraded my homeassistant from pi4 to pi 5

The USB to SATA adapter would work right in the USB 3 port.  It worked just fine in the USB 2 port. (except slower of course).  I had to buy a different USB-SATA adapter and I thought it was a fluke.

I upgrade a hostapd rasperry pi 4 to pi 5

The same wifi adapter I was previously using just failed in the USB 3 port.  However it works fine in the USB 2 port.
Question: how can I get my wifi adapter to work in a USB 3 port?
For this problem the only hints I got are this:
 
Failed to set beacon parameters
handle_probe_req: send failed
handle_probe_req: send failed

Handle_probe_req: send failed happens continuously for 100's of lines before I end it.

[    2.493610] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 1000fff000.mmc [1000fff000.mmc] using ADMA 64-bit
[    2.562731] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7612, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.570951] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[    2.578191] usb 1-2: Product: Wireless
[    2.582040] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc.
[    2.586674] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 000000000

Also

brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[    5.961761] mt76x2u 1-2:1.0: ASIC revision: 76120044
[    5.994216] mt76x2u 1-2:1.0: ROM patch build: 20141115060606a
[    6.018106] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8


Device is in USB 2 port right now
lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e8d:7612 MediaTek Inc. MT7612U 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0e8d MediaTek Inc.
  idProduct          0x7612 MT7612U 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 MediaTek Inc.
  iProduct                3 Wireless
  iSerial                 4 000000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x004a
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          5 BT_Config
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           8
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              1 WiFi_If
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x07  EP 7 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x0000f41e
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
    BESL value     1024 us
    Deep BESL value    61440 us
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         180 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled



what use is it to know that other people have problems with the USB ports?

"I upgraded my homeassistant from pi4 to pi 5" did you do a fresh installation? If you chose to ignore the recommended procedure expect  problems.

@Milliways  I tried fresh installs 5 times.  They all failed horribly with the specific sata to usb adapter.

@jsotola  Ignore that part, and help get my usb wireless lan adapter working on a USB 3 port.
